# Is it possible to select rows if a string column contains any number value?

Tags: sqlite

A particular column in my table is marked as a String type, however, more than likely, it will have an integer value mixed in with the string.

Here are some example rows:

```
"hello1"
"keys"
"Thom27"
"3for5"
```

I would like to be able to select the rows that have numbers in the string. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GLOB for that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblNames
WHERE Name GLOB '*[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

GLOB is the best answer (as mentioned above). GLOB supports REGEX like matching, which is more efficient than individual matches with LIKE.